# Trac after clean install. TracError: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: apache, centos, trac, permission-denied, ioerror

I have clean CentOS 6. I just install via `yum install httpd mysql-server, python, mysql-python`.

**First Step**

`$ trac-admin /home/tracprojects/main2 initenv`

> Project name: Main
>   SQL Connect string: mysql://trac@localhost:3306/trac (base exists, utf8, innoDB)
>
> OK.

`$ trac-admin /home/tracprojects/main2 deploy /var/www/html/`

> OK.

**Second Step**

Then I move `cgi-bin/trac.wsgi` to my `/cgi-bin/` server's alias folder. (mod_wsgi working well. NOT as a daemon. tested on wsgi scripts).

Then I've grant permissions to Apache user for whole directories I've create earlier. And add access from apache config. (order-allow-deny).

But when I open my browser and go to url, I've got this error message:

```
Internal Server Error
TracError: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/tracprojects/main2/VERSION'
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use SElinux (enabled by default)? With default SElinux I believe Apache can not access /home. You can check this by disabling SElinux temporarily ("setenforce 0" as root) and maybe restarting Apache. Also check /var/log/audit.log.

Comment: If you're on a Fedora system, you should have gotten a pop-up advising you of the problem and offering you several options to fix it, including permitting Apache to access home directories.

However, also check the context of the file: since it was created in a different folder, and then moved, its context might not match the folder in which it now lives. `ls -Z` shows contexts, and `restorecon` will set the context to the default for its new location (or `chcon` to manually specify one). CGI scripts default needing: `chcon -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t (FILE)`

Comment: Ooh, nifty troubleshooting cheat sheet: http://centoshelp.org/security/selinux-common-commands-troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions of '/home/tracprojects' etc. Apache runs as special user and simply may not be able to read into directories, read files, or even write files.

You may be better off using mod_wsgi daemon mode and telling mod_wsgi to run the process as a different user who can access that location. Even if do this, the WSGI script file directory still at least needs to be readable to Apache user.

Comment: I've got ISSUE: Trouble was in SELinux security politics.

I just run that: `grep VERSION /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M tracrule` and it does it.